# How to call my custom countries dropdown list in magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.3, countries

I need to call my custom countries dropdown list in magento2 checkout page. how to replace the default to my custom dropdown.

thanks in advance..

Comment: Why do you want to call your custom dropdown? If you want selected countries to be shown in the dropdown, Magento provides such option from the backend.

Comment: I need to display shipping countries different and billing countries different in my checkout page @mohit kumar Arora